# When does the social club site update the vehicle statistics?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, rockstar-games-social-club

Visting my profile on Rockstar's Social Club website my missions, trophies etc. will update usually within some hours after I played GTA V while signed in to my PS3 Account.

But the vehicle section still lists very few vehicles as driven. Some characters even have seemingly not used a car at all.

Is this just a synchronization bug by the Social CLub servers or are there special criteria on what counts as 'driven' for a vehicle? For example need it to be outside of a mission? Do I need to actually save the car in one of my garages?

Comment: I'm having the same problem on Xbox 360. My vehicle stats on social club aren't updating at all.

Comment: Rockstar announced in their recent Newswire article that they are still experiencing problems with server load and that not all features work as expected.

Answer (score -3):

Okay what help me when I was experiencing the same issue was, staying logged in for five minutes in social club on my MacBook, while my PS3 was running (XMB not GTA 5).

After five minutes the vehicle stats were completly up to date. I hope this helps.